# Why WSL2 connect mysql work for 127.0.0.1 but localhost not work?

Tags: docker, wsl-2

Why WSL2 connect mysql work for 127.0.0.1 but localhost not work?

If I install mysql image & create container and run it using `$ mysql -h localhost -u root -p` , system'll retrun `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'`

But when i use `$ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p` it's work.

```sh
$ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 11
Server version: 8.0.21 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> select 1
    -> ;
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

my full cmd record :

```sh
sa@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Users/TesT$ docker pull mysql
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/mysql
bf5952930446: Pull complete
8254623a9871: Pull complete
938e3e06dac4: Pull complete
ea28ebf28884: Pull complete
f3cef38785c2: Pull complete
894f9792565a: Pull complete
1d8a57523420: Pull complete
6c676912929f: Pull complete
3cdd8ff735c9: Pull complete
4c70cbe51682: Pull complete
e21cf0cb4dc3: Pull complete
28c36cd3abcc: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:6ded54eb1e5d048d8310321ba7b92587e9eadc83b519165b70bbe47e4046e76a
Status: Downloaded newer image for mysql:latest
docker.io/library/mysql:latest

sa@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Users/TesT$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
mysql               latest              3646af3dc14a        4 days ago          544MB

sa@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Users/TesT$ docker run -itd --name mysql-test -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456 mysql
74a7e237c26a96f069092e92a80d4e0c399150998723ea11cc37ddeea4d65ae3

sa@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Users/TesT$ sudo apt install mysql-client-core-8.0
[sudo] password for sa:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bridge-utils dns-root-data dnsmasq-base libidn11 ubuntu-fan

Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-client-core-8.0
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 45 not upgraded.
Need to get 4207 kB of archives.
After this operation, 64.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 mysql-client-core-8.0 amd64 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 [4207 kB]
Fetched 4207 kB in 10s (410 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-core-8.0.
(Reading database ... 32206 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-core-8.0_8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-core-8.0 (8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4) ...
Setting up mysql-client-core-8.0 (8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...

sa@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Users/TesT$ mysql -h localhost -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Comment: try `mysql -h mysql-test -u root -p`

Comment: it's not work `$ mysql -h mysql-test -u root -p
@ThanhNguyenVan Enter password:
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql-test' (11)` [image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/12729184/92560350-d9272100-f2a4-11ea-9734-b10023bd6b79.png)

Comment: container name `mysql-test` is running ?

Comment: try to connect to mysql container : mysql -h 172.17.0.1 -u root -p

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan yes,please look [image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/12729184/92561001-edb7e900-f2a5-11ea-9fba-5802cf0f2e13.png)

Comment: I had a similar problem but my issue was that some services like mysql were in windows subsystem for linux and others like nodejs app were in windows and solved it by running everything in windows subsystem for linux. The networking issues then disappeared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows thinks localhost is `::1`  IPv6 loopback.

Ubuntu 20.04 thinks localhost is `127.0.0.1`.

They are different addresses, that's why the name doesn't work.  You can bind servers to `0.0.0.0` for "all network adapters" which will include both ipv4 and ipv6.

EDIT: This isn't a complete solution as Windows networking still auto-misconfigures itself.  When it stops working, I do Start -> Network Reset and reboot my computer like it's 1985.

UPDATE: WSL2 is trash and you've been warned.  It was 1000 paper-cuts for stuff like this - that 2 years later never got fixed.

Comment: Kindly explain how to do this

Comment: @DrDeo, you can't get there from here.  Just install Ubuntu.

Comment: This is related to running the server in docker, not WSL. You can see from the error message that the client is trying connect via a UNIX socket. However, there is no UNIX socket because the server is running inside a docker container. The socket file is on the container and not on the host. When you use `-h 127.0.0.1` you force the client to connect via an INET socket. This hits the docker networking subsystem and so is correctly routed to the container. https://serverfault.com/questions/337818/how-to-force-mysql-to-connect-by-tcp-instead-of-a-unix-socket